# {Multiplexors} combine 2:1 to from 8:1

Tags: digital-logic, multiplexer

I have a question of combining 2:1 to form single 8:1 multiplexor

This is acheivable by using 7   2:1, with 4 of it at the first level, 3 of it at the second level, and 1 of it at the third level.  Then you just hook up the control bit of the first level together, and the second level together and so on. **But my question is for the 3 bits "control bits", do you need another decoder or something?**

Comment: No, nothing else.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, if you "control bits" are 101  (6 in decimal), then you just hook '1' to the first level, '0' to the second level, and '1' to the third level?

Comment: If the control bits are C B A (A = LSB, B = MSB) you can connect A to the control input of  each of the first set (4) of muxes, B to each of the second set, and C to the final mux. There are other ways that will work, but that makes sense to me.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, so C(MIDDLE BIT)--B(MSB)--A(LSB) ?

Comment: lsb controls 4 mux'es in the first stage, middle bit controls 2 muxes in the 2nd stage, msb controls 1 mux in the final stage.

Comment: See answer for schematic

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fR6Djn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>